# How to serve static Image path in img tag with webpack in React JS application

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working on a React application where in I am having img tag with hard coded image path like below in render function

```
import '../css/styles.scss';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { List } from './list';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}


render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
               < img src="images/logo.png" alt=""/> 
         );
    }
}

const root = document.getElementById('app-container');

ReactDom.render(<App />, root);
```

When I run application with webpack-dev-server, application runs fine and I can see image o webpage. However when i run application using webpack command, it generates build folder and and when I run application; I can't see image in webpage.
my webpack.config.js is :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'js/app.js'),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?sourceMap&camelCase&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          'sass-loader?sourceMap'
        ]
      }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html')
    })
  ]
}
```

I understand we can use file-loader in webpack to generate image folder in build folder and use `import image from "__path to image"`
However is there any way to serve direct image path mention in render function above ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use CopyWebpackPlugin.  This will copy your images from your src folder to build folder.  Then your app can resolve the relative urls.

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
....
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './src/images', to: 'images' },
    ]),
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution is you have to install url-loader.This is command
**npm install --save-dev url-loader**

then add following code in webpack.config file in your rules section.

```
{
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=25000'
    },
```

next import your image in your APP component.

**import logo from 'images/logo.png';**

and pass logo in img tag.Like this

**< img src={logo} alt=""/>**

```
import '../css/styles.scss';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { List } from './list';
import logo from 'images/logo.png';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}


render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
               < img src={logo} alt=""/> 
         );
    }
}

const root = document.getElementById('app-container');

ReactDom.render(<App />, root);
```

Comment: thanks, I already said this is one option, but i guess we need file-loader not url-loader ?